# Easiest possibility to send request from web to python

Tags: python, web

Since I freak out with everything web-dev related.

What is the easiest possibility to have a very simple web-page that only provides an input field, sends the input data to a python script and presents the return value from python.

Thank you

Comment: There are two disjoint parts to your question: (a) simple webpage that sends an input data, commonly called a "web form" (please do a web search), and (b) process that input. Few things to consider when you think about part (b) - (1) does the processing have to be done by Python only? (2) can the processing be done on the user's own computer (client side) using something like Javascript, or must it be done on the server side (perhaps PHP)? Hope this will help you think and search in the right direction. No need to freak out.

Comment: If PHP is available try to run the python script using `exec`, `system` or `passthru`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try bottle

```
import bottle 

app = bottle.app()



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """<HTML>
    <FORM method="POST">
    <INPUT name="input1">Please provide Input</INPUT>

    </FORM>
    </HTML>"""

@app.post('/')
def index_post():
    print(bottle.request.forms.keys())
    input1 = bottle.request.forms.get("input1")
    print("got", input1)
    return ("I got %s" % input1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```